# Nativescript : camera photo asset with nativescript-ocr

Tags: ocr, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to take a picture with the nativescript camera module and to run 
the nativescript-ocr module (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-ocr)  on it .

Here is my code :

```
public saveToGallery: boolean = true;
public keepAspectRatio: boolean = true;
public width: number = 300;
public height: number = 300;
private ocr: OCR;

constructor() {
    this.ocr = new OCR();

}

ngOnInit(): void { 
}


onTakePhoto() {
    let options = {
        width: this.width,
        height: this.height,
        keepAspectRatio: this.keepAspectRatio,
        saveToGallery: this.saveToGallery
    };
    takePicture(options).
        then((imageAsset) => {
            console.log("Result is an image asset instance");

            let img: ImageSource = new ImageSource();

            img.fromAsset(imageAsset).then((success) => {
                if (success) {
                    this.ocr.retrieveText({
                        image: img,
                        whitelist: "ABCDEF",
                        blacklist: "0123456789",
                        onProgress: (percentage: number) => {
                            console.log(`Decoding progress: ${percentage}%`);
                        }
                    }).then(
                        (result: RetrieveTextResult) => {

                            console.log(`Result: ${result.text}`);
                        }, (error: string) => {
                            console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
                        })
                }
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
}

onRequestPermissions() {
    requestPermissions();
}
}
```

Camera plugin works fine, takes and saves a picture, but when i'm running onTakePhoto i get this error message :

"Error in ocr.retrieveText: Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist!"

i'm not sure to use the .fromAsset the right way,
but i try a lot of thing to solve this problem

what i'm doing wrong?

> > > > > > > Resolve : i didn't create corectly my tesseract/tessdata folder